# Get value from element id instead of name in javascript

Tags: javascript, sum, getelementbyid

I have some line of javascript which is works well if it gets value from the same series of names. But I have a problem later when each values passed to another page which I'd like to break down which value is belongs to. So the question is how can I change the way the script calculate the value from 'name' to 'id'. As the codes below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //auto commas
    function doThousands(n) {
        n = '' + n;
        if (n.length < 4) return n;
        var c = n.length % 3;
        var pre = n.substring(0, c);
        return pre + (pre.length? ',' : '') + n.substring(c).match(/\d{3}/g).join(',');
    }
//sub total
    function checkTotal() {
        document.cc_form.total.value = '';
        var sum = <?=$days*$_rate*$_rooms?>;
        for (i=0;i<document.cc_form.cost.length;i++) {
            if (document.cc_form.cost[i].checked) {
                sum = sum + parseInt(document.cc_form.cost[i].value);
                }
            }document.cc_form.total.value = doThousands(sum);
        }
    </script>
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<form name="cc_form" id="cc_form" method="post" action="/">
<label for="transfer1"><input type="checkbox" id="transfer1" name="cost" value="800" autocomplete="off" onchange="checkTotal()" />&nbsp;Taxi (800 THB | 2 pax)</label><br />
<label for="transfer2"><input type="checkbox" id="transfer2" name="cost" value="1200" autocomplete="off" onchange="checkTotal()" />&nbsp;Mini Van (1,200 THB | 6 pax)</label><br />
<label for="xbed"><input type="checkbox" id="xbed" name="cost" value="1200" autocomplete="off" onchange="checkTotal()" />&nbsp;Extra Bed (1,200 THB)</label><br />
<input type="text" id="total" name="total" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp